# The conditional expectation of the error term in single index model

Tags: error

There is a statement in the "Non-parametric Economics" book chapter does not make sense to me. Here is the statement.

A semi parametric single index model is of the form
$$Y = g\left(X^{\prime}\beta_{0}\right) + u,$$
where $Y$ is the dependent variable, $X \in R^{q}$ is the vector of explanatory variables, $\beta_0$ is the $q\times1$ vector of unknown parameters, and $u$ is the error satisfying $E\left(u \mid X \right) =0$

Therefore, we have
$$E(Y\mid x) = g(x^{\prime}\beta_0).$$

Then, we define 
$$G(X_i^{\prime}\beta) \overset{def}{=} E(Y_i \mid X_{i}^{\prime}\beta) = E\left[ g(X_i^{\prime}\beta_0) \mid X_i^{\prime}\beta\right]$$.

Everything before the last equality makes sense to me. However, the book says that the last equality follows from the  fact that $E(u_i \mid X^{\prime}_{i}\beta) = 0$ for all $\beta$ since $E(u_i \mid X_i) = 0$. Could anyone explain why the fact is true? It doesn't seem obvious to me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put in the intermediate steps:

$$E(Y_i | X'_i \beta) = E[g(X'_i\beta_0) + u_i | X'_i \beta)] = E[g(X'_i\beta_0)|X'_i\beta_0] + E[u_i|X_i'\beta_0] = E[g(X'_i\beta_0)|X'_i\beta_0] + 0$$

The second equality follows from the linearity of expectations.  As to why

$$ E[u_i|X_i] = 0 \Rightarrow E[u_i | X_i'\beta_0] = 0, \forall \beta_0,$$

I can only provide an intuitive answer.  The event $\{X_i = x_i\}$ and the event $\{X_i\beta_0 = x_i\beta_0\}$ are the same event, as long as $\beta_0 \neq 0$.  So conditioning on one is the same as conditioning on the other.

Comment: I think I got this part. However, the step I don't understand is as follow. We have $E(u_i \mid X_i) = 0$ by the definition of the single index model. But why $$E(u_i \mid X_i) = 0 \Rightarrow E(u_i \mid X_{i}^{\prime}\beta)=0 \text{ for all } \beta$$. I realize it might be quite obvious, but I just couldn't wrap my head around.